# хочу достать каритинку элемент src в ответ выводит [ ]

Tags: python, парсер

хочу спарсить сайт и достать картинку с ответом  не понимаю что не так помогите с поиском ошибки

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
URL = "https://gdz.ru/class-6/matematika/a-g-merzlyak/1-rzdl-4/"
link = requests.get(URL)
soup = bs(link.text, "html.parser")
urlList = []
a = soup.find("src", class_="overtask")

print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для получения url картинки нужно искать класс **img** в **with-overtask**.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

URL = "https://gdz.ru/class-6/matematika/a-g-merzlyak/1-rzdl-4/"

response = requests.get(URL)
soup = bs(response.text, "html.parser")

image = soup.find("div", class_="with-overtask").find("img").get("src")
print(f"http:{image}")
```